# Spring Boot Logback Profile Logger Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

For my spring boot app, I am trying to setup logback so that logs are written to a file. I have defined 2 profile one for prod and one default. The prod one is supposed to write to a file and default is supposed to write to the default console(std out). While the prod profile seems to be working, when I run the default profile the logs don't print in the eclipse console - they too are logged to the file. What did I do wrong

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />

    <springProfile name="default">
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="prod">

        <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>app.log</file>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
                <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
                <!-- 60 days to keep -->
                <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
        <logger name="edu.aus" level="DEBUG"/>
        <root level="ERROR">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="logs/app.log"/>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, 
                it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="edu.aus" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

application.properties

```
# logging level
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.edu.aus=DEBUG

# output to a file
logging.file=app.log

# temp folder example
#logging.file=${java.io.tmpdir}/app.log

logging.pattern.file=%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n

logging.pattern.console=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

## if no active profile, default is 'default'
spring.profiles.active=default

# root level
#logging.level.=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what did you write in the included `*.xml`.
You are using CONSOLE, but I cannot see it in you code.If it is not rightly called, I think you should define CONSOLE like below：

```xml
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d|%-5level|%thread|%logger{40}|%L|%msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

put code above in `logback.xml` between `<configuration>` tag